# VSTS build project with reference to other solution

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repository that contains two solutions. One solution (in this case solution A) for a web project that has a reference to a project in the second solution (in this case solution B) (in the same repository).

When I build the web project in VSTS I pull the repository, build solution B, and then build solution B.

Build solution B work, but, the build of solution A is failed cause the reference dll of the project in solution B didn't found

Comment: Can you show the detail build logs here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1) Use project references. You don't need to depend on an assembly.

2) Use NuGet packages -- the shared piece is built via a CI process, turned into a NuGet package, and then published to a Packages feed. The dependent projects can reference the NuGet package and restore an appropriate version on build.

Which approach you should take depends on a lot of factors. If you're not worried about versioning, just use project references.

Comment: What do you mean "project references"? the reference from the other solution appears in the references list in the project

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said that it’s better to use NuGet packages.

Regarding reference the assembly file directly, refer to these steps:

1. Open your web project file through Notepad
2. Find the related reference and check Hintpath value, should be relative path.
3. Add Copy files task to your build definition (Before build solution A task) to copy corresponding assembly files to corresponding folder (per to that relative path)